# agregar una imagen en wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

hala yo quiero agregar una imagen con html que se ubica em la carpeta img pero coloco la ruta y no se coloca.

lo que coloco:

```
 <li>
    <img class="img-fluid" src="/img/fotos/1.jpg">
 </li>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por lo cual quiero que me indiquen de como hacerlo ya que soy nuevo en wordpress

Comment: Te recomiendo que investigues en google un poco sobre las rutas relativas y las absolutas, ya que ese es el problema por el cual no ves tus imágenes

Answer (score 1):

Prueba llamando a la funcion bloginfo( 'template_url' );
Ejemplo:

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/img/fotos/1.jpg">
```

Aunque primero verifica que la ruta sea correcta, la funcion `get_bloginfo( 'template_url' )` deberia devolver la ruta completa del tema, si estas usando un child-theme posiblemente debas usar `stylesheet_directory` en vez de `template_url`

Answer (score 1):

Tienes, en principio, dos formas de añadir la imagen:

1. Como lo estas haciendo desde una carpeta dentro del tema.
2. Añadiéndola como media desde el panel de administración de WordPress.

En el **primer caso**, debes [referenciar el theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) que estas utilizando en la url de la imagen. Te quedaría algo tal que así:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/fotos/1.jpg">
```

En el **segundo caso**, puedes añadir la url de la imagen cuando la añades como medio. Debería generarte algo como **https://tu-sitio.com/wp-content/2022/06/nombre-de-la-imagen.jpg**. En el código puedes usarla de esta manera:

```
<img src="/wp-content/2022/06/nombre-de-la-imagen.jpg">
```